# Gradle War adds extra jar files under WEB-INF/lib

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, war

I am new to Gradle. With Gradle I am having multi project build files. Most of the project build files are properly configured and works fine and generates correct output. I am trying to convert one of the projects from ANT build to Gradle build. I am able to compile Java files and able to generate WAR archive.

One thing I have noticed with generated WAR file is that there are additional JAR files included in WEB-INF/lib directory. When I build project from ANT build system then there are only few jar files included (approx. 10-12), but with gradle it includes lot many additional jar files (approx. 90-92). I have jar files in directory structure which should be included.

Here is dependency block from build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')
}
```

I am new to gradle system. So I might have missed some points to look after, but I don't know which are they. Can anyone please guide me which points to look after for dependency management in a multi project gradle build system? What is the solution for this issue came accross?

Comment: Any input on this please?

Answer (score 0):

You can add jars to WEB-INF/lib adding the desired folder to war plugin configuration:

```
war {
 classpath fileTree('desiredFolder') 
}
```

Extracted from  https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War.html

> classpath  The classpath to include in the WAR archive. Any JAR or ZIP
>   files in this classpath are included in the WEB-INF/lib directory. Any
>   directories in this classpath are included in the WEB-INF/classes
>   directory.

hopes this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why gradle add extra jars is because the libraries declare in dependencies could have other dependencies.

Try using *providedCompile* or *providedRuntime* to avoid add extra dependencies to war.

To add libraries try using *classpath* as describe in https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html

The section **Customizing** shows:

```
war {
from 'src/rootContent' // adds a file-set to the root of the archive
webInf { from 'src/additionalWebInf' } // adds a file-set to the WEB-INF dir.
classpath fileTree('additionalLibs') // adds a file-set to the WEB-INF/lib dir.
classpath configurations.moreLibs // adds a configuration to the WEB-INF/lib dir.
webXml = file('src/someWeb.xml') // copies a file to WEB-INF/web.xml 
}
```